# Prevent route access

Tags: symfony

I have built my menu via a controller and rendered it in my layout with 
`{{ render(controller('AppBundle:Menu:menu', {})) }}`

Here is my routing:

```
app_menu:
    path: /_menu
    defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Menu:menu}
```

I want to prevent direct access to the menu via `http://my-site.come/_menu`
The only way to see the menu should be when it's rendered in the layout.

How can I do it?

Comment: try simply removing the route annotation

Comment: Not sure to understand... If you're telling me to delete the line `path`, it won't work. Symfony needs the `path` to render the view. Deleting it will only give an error.

Comment: @Preciel remove your route definition completely not your `path` only.

Comment: Oh~ I thought the route was needed for the render. Can you write it as reply?! So I can validate it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need to access from web via an URL, simply don't add the routing definition. So simply remove the routing definition from the routing.yml